# Do I need to define student id as primary key and change the default id in eloquent orm in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this database of students in a school. Let's say for example the student id of one student is 098-123-123. I want that student number to be the primary key. Is it advisable to use string instead of increment? Do I need to change the structure of the table and change the default increment('id') in laravel? What would be the best practice here?

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('privillege');
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: The best practice is keep the primary key as `increments`. You can add another column for student number and make it `unique`. Example: `$table->string('student_number')->unique();`

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the auto-increment ID and use an other column for your own Student ID `098-123-123` that is indexed and unique. And then create a scope to be able to search quickly by this Student ID.

```
public function scopeFindByStudentId($query, $id)
{
    $query->where('student_id', '=', $id);
}
```

Comment: @Mushroom Thanks for the response. Yeah got your point. But the question now is, do I need to make student_id as string or integer?

Comment: If you have dashes like in your example it should be a string `$table->string('student_id', 11)` or whatever length you need.